# How to return a generic function from a non-generic function?

Tags: c#

This will probably be easiest to explain with an example.

So, let's start with the following `TryNTimes` function.

```
public static T TryNTimes<T>(Func<T> f, int n)
{
    var i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            return f();
        }
        catch
        {
            if (++i == n)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like

```
MyType x = TryNTimes(DoSomething, 3);
MyOtherType y = TryNTimes(DoSomethingElse, 3);
```

But I'm using this in many cases with the same `N`, so I'd like to make it easy to create a function that injects the `n` value into here.  So the use would be

```
var tryThreeTimes = CreateRetryWrapper(3);
MyType x = tryThreeTimes(DoSomething);
MyOtherType y = tryThreeTimes(DoSomethingElse);
```

The closest I could come up with was

```
public static Func<Func<T>, T> CreateRetryWrapper<T>(int n)
{
    return f => TryNTimes(f, n);
}
```

But that's not really what I want, because it forces me to specify `T` a-priori, so it's not really reusable in the way that I want.  I want to be able to delay the `T`, returning a generic function as a value.  Something like

```
public static Func<Func<_>, _> CreateRetryWrapper(int n)
{
    return f => TryNTimes(f, n);
}
```

Is this something that's possible in C#?

Comment: why not a class `RetryWrapper`, in wich the `TryNTimes` function is a member, and n is property? This may be an evasion of the question but that's how I think the right way in OOP/

Comment: @lomed Good workaround. I think the answer is going to be that no, C# doesn't allow generic values or something. So this would be a good alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

workaround:

```
class RetryWrapper 
{ 
    int n;
    public RetryWrapper(int _n) => n =_n;
    public T Try<T>(Func<T> f) => TryNTimes(f, n);
}
```

Use:

```
var tryThreeTimes = new RetryWrapper(3);
MyType x = tryThreeTimes.Try(DoSomething);
MyOtherType y = tryThreeTimes.Try(DoSomethingElse);
```

Comment: Any idea why you'd need an "object" rather than just a function though?

Comment: @DaxFohl I'm not sure I understand you, but I will answer you with a question: When should objects be used?

Comment: Well, per the question, I was looking for a way to return a plain generic function from a plain non-generic function.  But it looks like there's no such thing as a generic _value_ in C#, so there'd be no way to assign that return value to anything anyway. So this seems like the best workaround.

Answer (score 1):

```
class RetryWrapper
{
    readonly int n;

    private RetryWrapper(int n)
    {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public static RetryWrapper Create(int n)
    {
        return new RetryWrapper(n);
    }

    public T TryNTimes<T>(Func<T> f)
    {
        var i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                return f();
            }
            catch
            {
                if (++i == n)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
RetryWrapper.Create(3).TryNTimes(() => 16);
```